# Assembly - If statement to check for a valid number input not executing correctly

Tags: assembly, inline-assembly

So for a uni assignment we have to create an encryption/decryption program using C++ and Assembly. The program takes a 6 letter string and then executes the encryption/decryption part of the program. Both of those parts are working correctly, but we also have to check if the characters entered are alphanumeric. I'm trying to start off by just checking for a valid digit first, and then i can add the check for letters later on. This is the code I've got so far;

```
void get_char(char& a_character)
{
    a_character=(char) _getwche();

    __asm
    {
        push eax               // save value to the stack for later use
        mov eax, a_character   // store the character in EAX
        cmp eax, 0x30          // compare character with '0'
        jl invalid             // (character < 0) and is therefore invalid
        cmp eax, 0x39          // compare character with '9'
        jg invalid             // (character < 0) && (character > 9) so it is therefore invalid
        jmp valid              // character is within the accepted range and is therefore valid
    }

    __asm
    {
    invalid:
    }

    cout << "\n invalid > ";

    __asm
    {
    valid:
        pop eax
    }

    if (a_character == '\r' || a_character == '\n')
    {
        a_character = dollarchar;
    }
}
```

I expect the code to check if the value entered is < 0 and if it is, then jump to the invalid section and print a string saying that the value is invalid. And then also do the same for > 9. But for some reason regardless of what character I enter it just prints the invalid string anyway. I'm sure this is a really simple solution but I just cannot work out what is going wrong, and any solution I try just seems to cause a different problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `mov eax, a_character` <-- What you're putting in `eax` there is the address of `a_character`, since `a_character` is a `char` _reference_.

Comment: So changing it from a reference seems to solve the problem I'm having, although it has caused the code to no longer add the characters to the array. Is there a way of getting the actual value of a_character whilst keeping it as a reference?

Comment: Of course. Just dereference the address, e.g. `movzx eax,byte ptr [eax]`.

Comment: @Michael: or better, introduce a C variable `char tmp = a_character` that holds the char *value* you want.  In theory, the compiler could fill in `movzx eax, byte [tmp]` with an addressing mode that references `a_character` where the C outside the asm statement stored the char into the caller's pointer.  But probably it would just reserve extra stack space and store the char twice, once to `a_character` and once to `tmp`.  That's maybe still more efficient, and keeps the asm simpler, though.